# Cocoa Mail Framework

Tags: cocoa, email, account

I am wondering if anyone knows of a good Cocoa Mail framework that is updated for Leopard.  Nothing that I can find compiles on my system, and I need a integrated mail system (versus Mail.app).  I have tried: EdMessage, Pantomime, and MailCore. Maybe I'm doing something that makes these not compile, and if so please let me know.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these should build on 10.5 if their dependencies are satisfied; we can help you more effective if you let us see the errors reported while building.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben.  If I can, I think I would prefer to use EdMessage - But basically the framework that I would like to build on is whichever is easier to program with.  This is a small internal project, so I don't need this production level.  The errors that I get for EdMessage (test project from: http://github.com/tcurdt/edmessage/tree/b13d6a43c1e31b9b167c8ca74f7a7493e19f74c3/Test/TestApp) are...

Comment: EDCommon.framework/Headers/NSArray+Extensions.h:32: error: syntax error before 'NSUInteger'

EDCommon.framework/Headers/NSArray+Extensions.h:33: error: syntax error before 'NSUInteger'

EDCommon.framework/Headers/NSArray+Extensions.h:35: fatal error: method definition not in @implementation context

This is after importing the frameworks found in the download of EdMessage (as the ones linked in the file didn't exist).

Comment: It sounds like you’re building against an SDK that doesn’t have NSUInteger defined. Can you verify this in the Project Inspector?

Comment: @Ben Stiglitz  For some reason it had 10.4 selected, so I changed it to 10.5.  But now when it runs, it simply quits and loggs the following.

@executable_path/../Frameworks/EDMessage.framework/Versions/A/EDMessage Referenced from: /Users/me/Downloads/tcurdt-edmessage-b13d6a43c1e31b9b167c8ca74f7a7493e19f74c3/Test/TestApp/build/Debug/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp Reason: image not found

Comment: I've managed to fix that problem by moving both of the frameworks in a new "Copy Frameworks" folder in the target.  Thanks for all your help.